# Printed out Account Review

Tags: account, document, account-management, template

I have 100 accounts that I am reviewing. I have taken data from many different sources and now need to back this up with data that is printed out from either Salesforce or mail merged from an excel spreadsheet.

I could create a document template in SFDC but it seems that I would have to go into each account to click a button. Is there a better way? Some batch process that would print out my results?

A printed document is, in this case, necessary.

Comment: What do you need that a standard report could not offer you?

Comment: Text, description, layout, meaning, summary of opportunities. This is an executive report and line item reporting isn't going to cut it.

Comment: Could you give an example of some data and how you would like it to be used? This question is very broad.

Comment: Just a document with data from the account record, the last years opportunities.

Comment: You could use an app like conga, or draw loop.  Native document generation is one record at a time via extended mail merge.

Comment: I ran a mail merge in Word with the data in a spreadsheet. Then used another for the supporting evidence in a separate report.